# Where is the Phusion Passenger config file?

Tags: nginx, passenger

Where is the Apache module installed for Phusion Passenger? I want to adjust some of the config values found in "[Configuring Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_configuring_phusion_passenger)".

I don't know where this config file is. I've installed everything like the documentation says for Nginx.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's is a command `passenger-config --root` which shows Passenger's root. All other config should be in the Apache or Nginx config file, which means in `sites-enabled/your_site`.

Comment: e.g. /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your_site

Answer (score 1):

You configure Phusion Passenger through the Apache configuration file, just like with any other Apache module.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/nginx/conf.d/phusion-passenger.conf

on CentOS